# Install 13.10 on SSD fails

Tags: installation, boot, grub2, 13.10, ssd

Got some new parts today and decided to rebuild my main computer. Among the parts were a Crucial 240gb SSD.

I boot from the live-dvd and partition 200gb of the SSD as "/", and put "/home" on my trusty old 1tb SATA HDD.

Install seems to go fine, minus some hiccup where the reboot doesn't happen automatically, but I am immediately dumped to a grub rescue prompt with the message "error: no such partition" when I attempt to boot.

Any help or pointers welcome.

The reboot-hiccup happens when DVD is ejected, I get about a million of these:

[ various-numbers.various-numbers ] hub3-4.1:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 2 disabled

and am finally forced to press reset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `connect-debounce` is your USB ports disabled.

Do yourself a favor, install everything on the ssd, then follow this guide to migrate it to the other drive:
[Moving /home to Another Partition](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving)

Hope I helped!

Comment: Thanks for the tip, did almost just that and now everything is up and running almost the way i wanted it.